# Cocos2d-x C++ Error when I try to build macOS Version

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, macos, cocos2d-x

We develop an app, in ios version an works fine. But when we change to MacOS appear this error: Cannot initialize object parameter of type `cocos2d::Layer`. 
I think that this isn't the real error. Because in IOS versions works.
 I think that could be something about linked libraries, but we don't found it.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your custom class cpp files also target desktop. you have the option to do this when you add a new file into the project. If you are not sure wheter if your custom class files targeting desktop, you can check it by looking at Target Membership  section of the Utilities. make sure that both the mobile and desktop targets are ticked in order to target both.

[image]